# Какая клавиша назначена Input

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.

Допустим в Project settings - Input, я добавил свою клавишу (r - restart).

Вопрос в том как программно мне узнать что у Restart назначена клавиша r ?

Я хочу сделать надпись типа "Нажмите r для рестарта".

Неужели в Unity до сих пор не реализована данная возможность?

P.S. мне нужно узнать НЕ ЧТО было нажато, а какая клавиша у Input Restart, при том что её можно изменить в стартовом диалоговом окне

Comment: `при том что её можно изменить в стартовом диалоговом окне` - как вы хотите это менять?  и чем в таком случае не устраивает [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) ?  и еще вопросик: после того как вы узнаете что за кнопка отвечает, то как собираетесь вызвать код её нажатия?

Comment: "как вы хотите это менять?" при старте игры на Unity есть стандартное  диалоговое окно выбора разрешения экрана и изменения биндов, вот там и могут изменить r.

Comment: "то как собираетесь вызвать код её нажатия" зачем мне вызывать её нажатие? её нажимает игрок, я отловлю через Input.GetButtonDown("Restart")

Comment: Ну тогда юзайте `Input.GetKey` коли так и не парьтесь.....Берете клавишу по имени..... Но вообще, в нормальных действующих продакшн играх, а не демо — таких "стандартных окон" нет. Появляется заставочка игры и поехали. И инпуты, настройки и их переназначение в продакш играх контролируются внутри приложения.... Не смотря на это вы можете принудительно переназначить клавиши, не смотря на то, что там накликал юзер...... Так что вижу проблема ваша не велика. В другом бы случае я б написал о `FindProperty("m_Axes")` и поиске свойств там и плагинах ремапах.. Но в вашем случае достаточно ссылки выше

Comment: спасибо, а почему стандарт окно редко используют? Там же и выбор разрешения и качества и бинды. Зачем создавать велосипед. Та же игра Rust очень долгое время была с стандарт окном

Comment: `почему стандарт окно редко используют` - как минимум это некрасиво)) теряет некую серьезность, отталкивает....Вы тоже наверняка если захотите купить крутой монитор будете смотреть ЖК, а не трубку, не смотря на то, что смысл у них один и тот же. Подумаете: "ну чё это, какой-то прошлый век, не серьезно"..Причин может быть много, но как я писал: хорошо бы всё контролировать внутри. Даже переназначение клавиш. А то мало ли что....Кстати, если не хотите показывать это окно, то идете `File/Build Settings/Player Settings/Standalone Player Options/Display Resolution Dialog` ставите галочку `Disabled`

Comment: Я так и не понял причем тут Input.GetKey ? Этот метод возвращает true если нажата клавиша, вопрос был не про ОБРАБОТКУ нажатий клавиш, а о том как узнать какая клавиша назначена. Что у input Restart, стоит r клавиша, а не g,k,l. И потом эту букву вывести на экран "Нажмите [r] для рестарта"

Comment: А, что-то я пропустил этот момент с надписью `Нажмите клавишу ... для ...`. Я что-то думал будет написано `restart` и будет))) попробую позже написать

Comment: я пробовал вариант "SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset"". Но он работает только если скрипт в папке Editor, но если скрипт там я не могу его вызывать в других скриптах (в папке Scripts). Например создам в Editor скрипт InputButton в нём заполню Dictionary имя кнопки и текуще значение. Но не из другого скрипта получить значение, т.к. он не разрешает

Comment: Да,  к сожалению, видимо такой возможности сделать всё еще нет. Но, как я уже говорил, и смысла в этом нет, т.к. никто не ставит стандартные окна. Видимо поэтому разрабы забили на это.......А по поводу `Rust` могу сказать одно: там в окне конфигурации можно назначить только пару опций и то они абсолютно никак не влияют на игру. То есть если открыть саму игру и посмотреть клавиши управления, то назначенных клавиш не обнаружите. В окне конфига cancel назначите `U`, а в игре все равно будет `ESC`. Так что вот так. Ремаппинг надо позволять давать пользователю делать только внутри игры. Контроль.